# What character encoding are the following German words using?

Tags: character-encoding, extended-ascii

I'm trying to process a German word list and can't figure out what encoding the file is in. The 'file' unix command says the file is "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text". Most of the words are in ascii, but here are the exceptions:

```
ANDR\x82
ATTACH\x82
C\x82ZANNE
CH\x83TEAU
CONF\x82RENCIER
FABERG\x82
L\x82VI-STRAUSS
RH\x93NETAL
P\xF2ANGE
```

Any hints would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: To be clear, the hex codes above are C hex string literals so replace \xXX with the literal hex value XX.

Comment: None of this is German, though. Try French.

Comment: It comes from a German word list with other words like 'ZWOELFTAUSENDVIERHUNDERTDREIZEHNTEN' so my guess is either those 9 words are in there mistakenly or they're German.

Comment: They are mostly proper names, mostly of French origin. Maybe they were improperly encoded even when they were entered into the list? In CP437 they pick lowercase but otherwise correct-looking code points. There are many other code pages which share these code points, though; maybe there is one where the last one makes sense, too.

Comment: My best guesses for the last word after googling for a bit would be pïange (French) or pîange (Italian).  I speak neither (nor German, much) but am familiar enough with these languages to guess at word forms.  (For the record ZWOELF should properly be ZWÖLF in your example, though this OE digraph is a common workaround in Germany when proper diacritics are not available.)

Comment: So for the record my guesses would be André, attaché, Cézanne, château, conférencier, Fabergé, Lévi-Strauss, Rhônetal (actually German -- proper name, Rhône valley), pïange

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like [CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP437) or [CP852](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852), assuming the `\x82` sequences encode single characters, and are not literally four characters.  Well, at least everything else does, but the last line is a bit of a puzzle.